# Paired, Two Sample or Repeated Measures Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, paired-data

I'm trying to understand when to use a paired T-Test over a two sample T-Test. In most cases it's clear but I have the following hypothetical scenario.

A social media company claim offer a feature to increase the engagement of your posts. To test this you run an experiment on a number (30) of your social media posts.
You create two versions of each post, one with the 'boost' feature and one 'normal' (control) post. People are prevented from seeing both versions. You measure the engagement rate (engagements / people who saw the post) for each.

The resulting data will have 3 columns

1. Post identifier (e.g title)
2. Control engagement rate
3. Treatment (boosted) engagement rate

Which would be the most appropriate test statistic to use?

A paired test because you're comparing the engagement rate of the same subjects (the posts) under two different conditions?

A two sample test because you're comparing the behaviour of two different populations (the people who saw each post)?

A different test entirely?

The hypothesis being tested is that there is no difference in engagement rate between the two sets of posts. Is the correct null hypothesis that the mean of the differences in engagement rates is 0 or that the mean engagement rates of the two samples are the equal?

How would the answers change if instead you were testing the engagement rates of two different demographics, e.g people aged 30+ vs people aged under 30, with the same experiment design?

Comment: Generally, the matched pair test is measuring the 2 states of the same subject.  For example blood pressure before and after taking a drug.  The two same is when the subjects are different such as in this case.

Comment: So in the example scenarios the subjects being tested are the people who see the social media posts, not the posts themselves?

Comment: In the example above, you have 1 population seeing the treatment (boost) and a second population seeing the control.  So the 2 sample t-test is the better test.